# Why is the content of a div impacted by its display?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Summary**: I would like to have two chunks of text side by side (contained in a `div`), these two chunks being managed through `flexbox`. Their content is however impacted by the `display` of the parent `div`.

(The code below is in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/trdoL31v/))

Why does the following code

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex">
    this is the content of the left box
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    this is the content of the right box
    <p>
      with some paragraphs
    </p>
    <p>
      more paragraphs
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

displays as

[image]

I was expecting the two paragraphs to be below "this is the content of the right box". Why do they follow the row alignment of the `div`s with class `flex`?
How can I prevent them from doing so? (I was under the impression that `display: flex` would only cover the `div` containers, but the contents of these `div`s would be rendered as default positioning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the children of a flex-container are flex-items and lose their default display properties.

Even text nodes...

> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

From the [**Spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)

> A flex item establishes a new formatting context for its contents. The type of this formatting context is determined by its display value, as usual. However, **flex items themselves are flex-level boxes, not block-level boxes**: they participate in their container’s flex formatting context, not in a block formatting context.

So, to achieve the layout you want, make sure the child divs are not `display:flex`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.flex div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="">
    this is the content of the left box
  </div>
  <div class="">
    this is the content of the right box
    <p>
      with some paragraphs
    </p>
    <p>
      more paragraphs
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Following your answer I started to experiment with two classes (`row` for the "this is the content ..."  and `column` for the paragraphs) but your solution with empty `div`s is better.